# Apache 2.4 portability of python cgi-bin scripts between Windows and Linux

Tags: python, apache, wsgi, shebang

I am currently developing locally on Windows but then need to upload my files to a Linux server.  However, I'm running into a problem where I need to include a shebang at the top of each of my files to tell Apache which python application to run, and that will naturally be different on Windows and Linux, such that I would need to change all of my files as part of uploading them to Linux.  Is there a way to either remove the need for the shebang or provide a shebang that works under both Windows and Linux?

my httpd.conf

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
    LoadFile "C:/Python/Python36-32/python36.dll"
    LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Python/Python36-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win32.pyd"
    WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python/Python36-32"
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Python/Web"
    <Directory "C:/Python/Web">
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes Includes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        DirectoryIndex index.py
    </Directory>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
</VirtualHost>
```

if my index.py includes the shebang, e.g. it looks like:

```
#!C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
print("Content-Type: text\html\n")
print("Heelolo ->>>>>>>>")
```

--> On Windows, I get the expected result:

```
Heelolo ->>>>>>>>
```

If I don't include the shebang, e.g.:

```
print("Content-Type: text\html\n")
print("Heelolo ->>>>>>>>")
```

I get the following message in my apache error.log

```
[Fri May 26 14:05:31.326900 2017] [win32:error] [pid 4700:tid 1972] [client 127.0.0.1:50743] AH02102: C:/Web/Hello/index.py is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line
```

Any ideas how I can make this work cross-platformly?

Comment: What's your question? How to run without the line Apache tells you that it is required?

Comment: current i code on window and shebang in window: #!C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe . i will publish on Linux ex: #!usr/python/ --> i don't want change in each file *.py when publish my code! tks!

Comment: I tried to edit your question to make it clearer; I was tempted to remove the WSGI entirely, because that seems like a red-herring if you're calling all of your python scripts via cgi, but Graham's answer would then make no sense, and he has a valid point that using mod_wsgi would not be the worst idea; from personal experience, django (which can run behind mod_wsgi although if I run it on Windows for development, I'm likely to use the built in dev server) runs just fine without needing to fix shebangs between Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

Although you have tried to load mod_wsgi, you got it wrong and haven't told Apache to host any WSGI applications anyway. You also haven't converted your Python web application to be a WSGI application. See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

and also go learn about a simple Python web framework like Flask rather than try and do things from scratch.

Before trying to that though, also remove the conditional for `wsgi_module`. That is, instead of:

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
    LoadFile "C:/Python/Python36-32/python36.dll"
    LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Python/Python36-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win32.pyd"
    WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python/Python36-32"
</IfModule>
```

you should have just:

```
LoadFile "C:/Python/Python36-32/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Python/Python36-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win32.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python/Python36-32"
```

The conditional meant those directives would only be applied if the module had already been loaded. Problem is the module was loaded within that check, so obviously it wasn't going to be loaded.